# Error: error: expected ')' before 'postData'

Tags: objective-c, nstimer

How to fix this error ?

```
Error: error: expected ')' before 'postData'

NSTimer *timer;
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0                                         target:self
selector: @selector(postData:@"xyz")
userInfo:nil

                                    repeats: YES];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions called as selectors from timers cannot have parameters. If I remember correctly, you can use userInfo, which passes an array or dictionary to the selector.

do something like this:

```
NSTimer *timer;
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0
         target:self
         selector: @selector(postData:)
         userInfo:@"xyz"
         repeats: YES];

- (void)postData:(NSTimer*)timer {
    NSLog(@"userInfo = %@", timer.userInfo);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When we read the documentation of the method you are using, it seems it's not correctly called :

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0
target:self
selector:@selector(postData:)
userInfo:nil
repeats:YES];
```

And your postData must have the following signature :

```
- (void)postData:(NSTimer*)theTimer
```